# How can I upgrade Typo3 4.2.6?

Tags: typo3

I have a Typo3 4.2.6 Version running.

To which version should I upgrade? (Can I upragde to 6.x?)

How should I do the upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest it to be upgraded to the latest version of typo3 4.7. Upgrading the site to typo3 6.x won't be a good choice as there's exists lot of open issues in typo3 forums regarding the upgrade to typo3 6.x. Most of the extensions in typo3 4.x won't work smoothly in typo3 6.x. So I suggest an upgrade to the lastest version typo3 4.7.
For **typo3 4.6 onwards need PHP 5.3** otherwise you can upgrade to 4.5.x.

How to upgrade typo3?

Check this link: **https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/how-to-upgrade-typo3-version/**

I've once successfully upgraded typo3 4.2 to 4.7 in a step by step way (4.2 to 4.4, 4.4 to 4.5 and 4.5 to 4.7). The issues after typo3 upgrade were solved using methods mentioned under "**Some simple ways to find out the errors/issues after upgrading typo3!**" in the above link.

Answer (score 6):

You should upgrade to 4.5 in an first step. The Version 4.5 is a LTS (Long Term Support) Version, the end of maintenance is in 3/2015 (see https://typo3.org/download/). I would not recommend to update to 6.0 now. Many extensions are not yet compatible and they changed a lot. At least the end of maintenence is the same as with 4.5.

Comment: I agree 4.5 is the way to go because of its LTS and the fact that your site is fairly old.

Comment: The current LTS is TYPO3 6.2 so this answer is obsolete

Answer (score 3):

Migration

STEP FOR UPGRADING TO 6.2

1)take a backup of old site (Dont forget to take backup of Database)

2)check if any extension installed globally make it local means (remove extension from /typo3/ext/ and install from TYPO3 TER which stored in folder /typo3conf/ext/ )

3)upload folder "typo3" of newly downloaded TYPO3 version

4)create folder "typo3_src" in root

5)remove "t3lib" folder

6)upload index.php from root folder

7)go to typo3 BE, go to install tool

8)click on  "System environment" and check if there is no error. if error exists solve the error.

9)click on "Folder structure" and try to solve as much error as you can.

10)click on "Upgrade Wizard"

11)perform all update wizard Section like 
    "Migrate all file relations from tt_content.image and pages.media"
    "Migrate all file links of RTE-enabled fields to FAL" etc...

12)click on Link "Go to Database Analyzer" at the end of "Upgrade Wizard" page.
    or
    click on "Important actions"

13)Go to "Database analyzer" section and click on "Compare current database with specification"

14)perform execution in section "Database analyzer"

15)Click on "All configuration" and Go to "$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']" and change the value of "[SYS][compat_version]" to 6.2

16) perform "Clear all cache" from "Important actions"

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from TYPO3 4.1 to 6.1 using this procedure:

1. Export all the content to .t3d. (If too large, make it in chunks)
2. install 6.1 and all your plugins.  (This ensures the DB has all needed tables).
3. Copy the old fileadmin/ content into the 6.x fileadmin/
4. Import .t3d
5. Fix plugins problems, i.e. deprecated functions etc.

It is wise to try it first in your Windows local machine.